# In-app updates for Android App on Microsoft App Center

Tags: android, visual-studio-app-center

We are trying to get in-app updates working for our Android application on App Center.  The code looks like this:

```
    Distribute.setListener(object : MyDistributeListener() {})
    AppCenter.start(
        application, "[SECRET GOES HERE]",
        Distribute::class.java, Analytics::class.java, Crashes::class.java)
    Distribute.setEnabled(true)
```

We created an "Alpha Test" group and used Jenkins to publish a release version of our application.  From App Center we distributed the release to our alpha group.  The alpha group got an email and they installed the application.  When the code above ran we saw an error that says that In-app updates have been disabled because the release was either side-loaded or downloaded using a browser in private mode.  I've tried just about everything I can think of to figure this out.  Hoping someone can shed some light on what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:  Turns out we had a Hockey App dependency that was not removed when moving to App Center.  Once this dependency was removed things started working.